# C hack: replace printf to collect output and return complete string by using a line buffer

Tags: c, string, swift, char, stdout

Got this great C program I'd like to embed into an iOs app.
One passes command line arguments to it and the results are printed to stdout via printf and fputs - like with all the good old unix programs.

Now I'd like to just edit main and the print functions to use my own printf function which collects all the output that normally goes to stdout and return it at the end.

I implemented a solution by using a line buffer to collect all the printfs until the newline. 
And a dynamic char array whereto I copy when an output line is finished.

The charm of this solution is - it's kind of tcl'ish: just throw everything into a text line and if its complete store it. Now do that as long as necessary and return the whole bunch at the end ...

**And here the question:** 
It works - but as I am fairly new in "real" programming - i.e. C and Apples "brandnew" Swift - am not sure wheter this is a good solution. Is it? And if not - what would you suggest? Thank you very much!

Here follows the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

// outLineBuffer collects one output line by several calls to tprntf
#define initialSizeOfReturnBuffer 10 // reduced for testing (would be 16*1024)
#define incrSizeOfReturnBuffer 5     // reduced for testing (would be 1024*1024)
#define outLineBufferMaxSize 4095
char outLineBuffer[sizeof(char)*outLineBufferMaxSize] = "";
char *tReturnString;
size_t sizeOfReturnBuffer, curPosOutBuffer = 0, lenOutLine = 0;
```

With the replacement tprntf for all the original printf and fputs:

```
// replace printf with this to collect the parts of one output line.
static int tprntf(const char *format, ...)
{
    const size_t maxLen = sizeof(char)*outLineBufferMaxSize;
    va_list arg;
    int done;

    va_start (arg, format);
    done = vsnprintf (&outLineBuffer[lenOutLine], maxLen-lenOutLine, format, arg);
    va_end (arg);
    lenOutLine = strlen(outLineBuffer);

    return done;
}
```

And the function when we complete one output line (everywhere \n is printed):

```
// Output line is now complete: copy to return buffer and reset line buffer.
static void tprntNewLine()
{
    size_t newSize;
    long remainingLenOutBuffer;
    char *newOutBuffer;

    remainingLenOutBuffer = sizeOfReturnBuffer-curPosOutBuffer-1;
    lenOutLine = strlen(outLineBuffer)+1; // + newline character (\n)
    remainingLenOutBuffer -= lenOutLine;

    if (remainingLenOutBuffer < 0) {
        newSize = sizeOfReturnBuffer + sizeof(char)*incrSizeOfReturnBuffer;
        if ((newOutBuffer = realloc(tReturnString, newSize)) != 0) {
            tReturnString = newOutBuffer;
            sizeOfReturnBuffer = newSize;
        } else {
            lenOutLine += remainingLenOutBuffer; //just write part that is still available
            remainingLenOutBuffer = 0;
        }
    }

    snprintf(&tReturnString[curPosOutBuffer], lenOutLine+1, "%s\n", outLineBuffer);

    curPosOutBuffer += lenOutLine;
    outLineBuffer[0] = 0;
    lenOutLine = 0;
}
```

And a little main to test it (without swift - e.g. plain gcc):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    sizeOfReturnBuffer = initialSizeOfReturnBuffer*sizeof(char);
    if ((tReturnString = malloc(sizeOfReturnBuffer)) == 0) {
        return 1; // "Sorry we are out of memory. Please close other apps and try again!";
    }
    tReturnString[0] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        tprntf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    tprntNewLine();

    tprntf("%s", "ABC\t");
    tprntf("%d", 12);
    tprntNewLine(); // enough space for that ;-)
    tprntf("%s", "DEF\t");
    tprntf("%d", 34);
    tprntNewLine(); // realloc necessary ...
    tprntf("%s", "GHI\t");
    tprntf("%d", 56);
    tprntNewLine(); // again realloc for testing purposes ...
    printf("tReturnString at the end:\n>%s<\n", tReturnString); // contains trailing newline
    return 0;
}
```

The call from swift will the be as follows (using [CStringArray.swift](https://gist.github.com/neilpa/b430d148d1c5f4ae5ddd))

```
let myArgs = CStringArray(["computeIt", "par1", "par2"])
let returnString = mymain(myArgs.numberOfElements, &myArgs.pointers[0])

if let itReturns = String.fromCString(returnString) {
    print(itReturns)
}

freeMemory()
```

Comment: If the program works but you want to do it better you should post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: All right thank you!
Moved it to [codereview - same question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113651/c-hack-replace-printf-to-collect-output-and-return-complete-string-by-using-a-l)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no code-review site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that tcl has many optimizations and I suggest you also optimize the code; then your approach can be viable.

Check your frequent use of `strlen`, which every time goes through all the (many) characters to count the length - use information about its length, for example maintain a `char *outLineBufPtr`. Also use `strcat` to append \n to `outLineBuffer` instead of using the expensive `vsnprintf` function, or just copy the char manually, as `*outLineBufPtr++ ='\n';` .

To implement a higher-level concept such as yours, you must start thinking in machine cycles so the higher-level concept does not become "expensive".

Comment: Improved performance by better `strlen` calls - if you are interested in the final version please see [codereview answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113651/c-hack-replace-printf-to-collect-output-and-return-complete-string-by-using-a-l/114153#114153). There is even a complete Xcode project [swift-C-string-passing](https://github.com/oot77/swift-C-string-passing) on github available now...
Thank you for your thoughts!